# Is there a way to pickout data based on associations using R?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

If I have a data set like this:

```
names <- c("Dave", "Ashley", "Drew")
score1 <- c(5, 1, 3)
opponent <- c("Drew", "Dave", "Ashley")
x <- cbind(names, score1, opponent)
x
y <- as.numeric(ifelse(x[, 3]==x[1, 1], x[1, "score1"], ifelse(
        x[, 3]==x[2, 1], x[2, "score1"], ifelse(
        x[, 3]==x[3, 1], x[3, "score1"], 1))))
y <- (y * score1)
x <- cbind(x, y)
x
```

Can I create a loop, to create a new column, where the number in the "score1" column is multiplied by the number from the "y" column from a different row. For instance, create a new column where the values at [1, 2] would be 5 since "Dave" had "Drew" in his row so "Dave"’s "score1" column “5” is multiplied by "Drew"’s "score1" column “3”. Is there a way to do this in a loop that would work for a hundred rows and a hundred columns? Currently, the only way I know to do it is to write a ton of "ifelse" statements like above.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a self join. Although, you'll have to be careful of duplicates if any names are repeated.:

```r
names <- c("Dave", "Ashley", "Drew")
score1 <- c(5, 1, 3)
opponent <- c("Drew", "Dave", "Ashley")

x <- data.frame(names,score1,opponent)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
new_df <- left_join(x,x[,-3],by=c("opponent"="names"))
new_df
#>    names score1.x opponent score1.y
#> 1   Dave        5     Drew        3
#> 2 Ashley        1     Dave        5
#> 3   Drew        3   Ashley        1
new_df <- mutate(new_df,y=score1.x * score1.y)
new_df
#>    names score1.x opponent score1.y  y
#> 1   Dave        5     Drew        3 15
#> 2 Ashley        1     Dave        5  5
#> 3   Drew        3   Ashley        1  3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>